# Is $Set$ a 2-category?

Tags: category-theory, enriched-category-theory

I've read that $Rel$ (the category of sets and relations) is a 2-category by considering 2-morphisms to be inclusion of relations. Is $Set$ also a 2-category by considering 2-morphisms to be inclusion of functions (as relations)? I can't find the reason why this is not true.

Comment: Maybe you want to consider the *partial functions* as morphisms between sets?

Comment: @Berci In that case we have a 2-category again?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Give two sets $A,B$, and $f,g:A\to B$, if $f\subseteq g$ as relations, then $f=g$.

So this is a trivial 2-category - the only 2-maps are the identity maps - but it is a 2-category.

So it is a $2$-category in exactly the same way that any category can be made a $2$-category.